# Order of evaluation regarding Lambda functions in Python

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, callstack

I have the following code snippet:

```
def foo(a):
    return lambda b: b(b(a))
def bar(p):
    return lambda q: p(q)
n = (bar)(bar)(foo)(5)(lambda x:x*x)
print(n)
```

The output is `625`, but I don't get how it is evaluated, or rather, how the order of evaluation is.

How does the call stack look like?

I noticed that `(foo)(5)(lambda x:x*x)` is equivalent to `(lambda x:x*x)((lambda x:x*x)(5))` because in this case, `a` is `5` and `b` is `lambda x:x*x` and thus `(foo)(5)(lambda x:x*x)` will give `625`.

If that is the case, then why does `(bar)(bar)(625)` evaluate to a function (`<function bar.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000001897D9183A8>`), and not the number `625` as expected?

Comment: Note that `bar(p)(q) == p(q)` so it's absolutely useless given the limitations of lambda functions, especially in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are evaluated from left to right here. This is how it's evaluated:

1. ```
   (bar)(bar)(foo)(5)(lambda x:x*x)
   ```
2. ```
   (bar)(foo)(5)(lambda x:x*x)
   ```
3. ```
   (foo)(5)(lambda x:x*x)
   ```
4. ```
   (lambda x:x*x)((lambda x:x*x)(5))
   ```
5. ```
   (lambda x:x*x)(25)
   ```
6. ```
   625
   ```

Comment: Why is it that `bar` can just be removed in lines 2 and 3?

Comment: @lefatohy `(bar)(bar)` is the same as `bar(bar)`. That evaluates to `lambda q: bar(q)` which is the same as `bar`.